# IOS 6 App Upgrade To IOS 7

Tags: ios, screen, upgrade

I want to Upgrade My App From IOS 6 To IOS 7...
    My App is Universal and For Upgrade to IOS 7 i have created Two Different XIB Files one
    for IOS 6 and One For IOS 7..and i have Complete the Upgrade but the Problem is My App is Running Perfect in IOS 7 4 inch Simulator...but when i Run My App in IOS 7 3.5 Simulator or Device then its Graphics and Data is not display in its proper Place...and sometime it crash...

```
i have also used Macro Below..
#define iPhone5 @"iPhone 5"
#define iPhone @"iPhone"
#define iPad @"iPad"

#define IS_IPHONE ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model]hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_IPOD ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model]hasPrefix:@"iPod touch"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GET_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_HEIGHT_GET_568)
#define IS_IPAD ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model]hasPrefix:@"iPad"])
```

Comment: i Got the Answer: Follow the Step Below to Upgrade Your App From IOS 6 To IOS 7..and its Also Work Fine in IOS 6 iPhone,ipad Simulator and IOS 7 iPhone 3.5 inch and 4 inch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i Have Got the Answer:
Follow the Step Below to Upgrade Your App From IOS 6 To IOS 7 and its Working Fine in Below Simulator
IOS 6: iPhone , iPad
IOS 7: iPhone 3.5 inch , iPhone 4 inch, iPad

**Follow the Step Below to Upgrade Your App**

First Create Macro in App Delegate.m File

#define iPhone5 @"iPhone 5"
#define iPhone @"iPhone"
#define iPad @"iPad"

#define IS_IPHONE ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model]hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_IPOD ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model]hasPrefix:@"iPod touch"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GET_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_HEIGHT_GET_568)
#define IS_IPAD ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]model]hasPrefix:@"iPad"])


**Now in Application didFinishLaunching Option Method**

//Check IOS Whether it is IOS 6 OR IOS 7

 NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

    NSLog(@"IOS VERSION================%@",version);

    BOOL isAtLeast6 = [version hasPrefix:@"6."];
    BOOL isAtLeast7 = [version hasPrefix:@"7."];

if (isAtLeast6)  // if IOS Version 6 Then
    {
            if (IS_IPAD) //if IOS Version 6 and iPad Then
            {
                NSLog(@"IOS 6 Ipad Called");
                viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];

            }
            else  // if IOS 6 and iPhone The
        {
                NSLog(@"IOS 6 iPhone Called");
                viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        }
}
else if (isAtLeast7)
    {
        if (IS_IPHONE_5)
        {
            viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            [viewController1 setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];//Automatically Set UI For IOS 7
            NSLog(@" IOS 7 iPhone Called");

        }
        else
        {
            viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
            [viewController1 setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to look at `Autolayout` to solve the device screen issues. It is not easy to learn but once you get hold of it, it takes care a lot of UI issues.

Using Autolayout, you will not need to load two XIBs to support iOS6 and 7 as well.
Refer:
[Official Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)
       [Raywenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

Creating two .xib for iOS 6 and iOS 7 is not a good idea, main UI difference in iOS 6 and iOS 7 is that iOS 7 has extra 20px. you just have to handle these extra 20px. Xcode has given  you control to handle this.

See this post [Display screen for iOS6 and iOS7 in simulator is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345000/display-screen-for-ios6-and-ios7-in-simulator-is-different/20345195#20345195)

Answer (score 0):

You should not bother about the UI of iOS6 and iOS7, Use System Elements ( UINavigationbar, UISwitch ,UIbutton,etc..) their appearance will be change according to iOS version.

From Apple Doc:

> If business reasons require you to continue supporting iOS6 or
>   earlier, you need to choose the most practical way to update the app
>   for iOS7. The techniques you choose can differ, but the overall advice
>   remains the same: First, focus on redesigning the app for iOS7.
>   Then—if the redesign includes navigational or structural changes—bring
>   these changes to the iOS6 version as appropriate **(don’t restyle the
>   iOS 6 version of the app to use iOS7 design elements, such as
>   translucent bars or borderless bar buttons)**.

reference: [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)

Comment: @Chiquis & Virsu MCA : i will Go through the Documentation..thanks