# iOS Simulator Ignores Half of the Screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios-simulator, screen

My app is working fine in iOS 7 , but when I simulate it in iOS 6 simulator , it seems , that it only loads top half of the screen. How can I solve this ?

This is an screenshot of how the view is in the storyboard builder and in the simulator :

[image]

Comment: What is the size of your view?

Comment: it's a default view controller that I dragged to storyboard.
It's not about the view! Look at where the top status bar is rendered in simulator and weird black boxes on top and bottom !

Comment: Ohk may be you should add the proper launch images.

Comment: Did set all the launch images. No progress !

Comment: Get Spark Inspector to see what is happening with your views. No changes are necessary to your code to use it and it has a 30 day free trial.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a splash screen (Default.png) of (640 × 1136)... without this app treated app as its iphone 4s & below device

[image]

Comment: Did set all the launch images. No progress !

Comment: You have to remove all "Images.xcassets" and then add launch images again.. in xcode 5.  I am adding a screen shot in my answer. Please review it.

Comment: I did that , but no help !
Apparently, It pays no attention to my launch images. Even though I have set all the images , it uses other images with very small resolutions as the launch image. I deleted them all, and now it is using "App's Icon" as Launch image :O !!!

Comment: I had the same issue because I removed the ScreenLaunch.Storyboard from the info.plist file. After creating a new storyboard and reassigning it in info.plist, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

set your iPhone retina 4 launch image 640*1136

[image]

Comment: Did set all the launch images.
No progress !

Comment: image resolution actual size. did you hide status bar

Comment: No, I didn't hide status bar

Comment: No , I got no warnings

Comment: link your project if possible

Comment: did you change your setting lauchimage to asset catlog

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the UI for iOS7 as well as iOS6.

1. Just open your storyboard and then click on assistant editor.
2. Now open storyboard preview in assistant editor.
3. There is a button in assistant editor at right hand bottom corner which says iOS7 or later, click on it and select iOS6 or earlier.
4. Now you can see the UI for both iOS7 and iOS6 side by side on the screen.
5. Now  select a particular view controller and then select size inspector.
6. In size inspector you just need to set the iOS6/7 Deltas for iOS6 screens.

That's it.

check this url too :
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html

If you have any problem then let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out the same thing by reading the answer here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345000/display-screen-for-ios6-and-ios7-in-simulator-is-different

I tested this on one of my view controllers and it got fixed.
But other view controllers' objects are not getting fixed by setting this delta ! Do u know why ? :-/

Comment: You need to set the delta for all the view controllers individually. Are you doing that??

Comment: Yeah , But what I was doing wrong was to set the delta same in all controllers ( Some had Nav bar and some hadn't ) !
And that was the problem !

Answer (score -1):

This happens because of the resolution of iOS6 is lesser than iOs 7 simulator. You can use Autolayout option  to solve this issue.

Comment: I cannot do that !
Deployment target is iOS 5+ !
Auto layout is not supported

Comment: This is not true, iOS 6 supported 4" devices and worked just as well with layoutmasks.

Comment: When I check AutoLayout box. The project does not build anymore !
I got an error saying : Using Auto Layout Prior to iOS 6.0 is not Allowed !